# Routing a Meteor/React app to give it a plain vanilla HTML home page

Tags: meteor, routes, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use Meteor with React to serve a web site, but I want the default home page to be plain vanilla HTML. Like this:

`https://meteor.example.com/        => HTML page with no JavaScript`
`https://meteor.example.com/meteor/ => fully reactive Meteor experience`

I understand that I can put a plain index.html page in the `/public` folder, but then it needs to be addressed specifically as `https://meteor.example.com/index.html`.

I have not been able to find a tutorial that addresses this particular situation.

Comment: Have you looked into using WebApp to define a server side route to serve up a static page? https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Comment: @DerrickGremillion This looks promising but I see no information on where the WebApp code should be put

Comment: @JamesNewton the `WebApp` package uses the [connect API](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) which works like an express route. @Derrick Gremillion do you want to provide a minimal `WebApp` example for a `/` route? If not, I could provide one.

Comment: @Jankapunkt A minimal `WebApp` example for a `/` route would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I've added a simple example to get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution which does not require any changes to the Meteor app. I'm using nginx to serve the Meteor site. I get the app to run on a local port, and set up a proxy rule in nginx:

```
server {  
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;
  charset utf-8;

  location ~ /(.+) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

As I understand it, this passes the url request to the Meteor app. If there is an `index.html` file in the `public/` folder, this will be served instead of the Meteor app when a request is made for `http://example.com/`.

(If I use `location /` instead of `location ~ /(.+)`, as I was doing originally, then a request for  `http://example.com/` is treated as a request for the default page from Meteor.)

**DEPLOYING**

For production, I create a package using...

```
meteor build --server-only ../example-package
```

... which I upload to the server and unzip. I then `cd` into `bundle/programs/server` and run `npm install --production` as the user which will be running the app. I then add folders as`bundle/tmp/` and `bundle/public/` and put my static `index.html` file and all the CSS and other files it requires in the `public/` folder.

Currently I am using `export ROOT_URL=http://localhost && export PORT=3000 && node main.js` to start the app, but I plan to use a [Phusion Passenger Standalone](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/deploy/meteor/) as soon as I have jumped through all the right hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using [WebApp](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) with [Assets](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html)
The following code would go into a server side only file for example /server/main.js in a meteor project

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/home', (req, res, next) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    const html = Assets.getText('home.html');

    res.end(html);
});
```